# Angular Datatables: How to append one key value pair to the every JSON object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, angular-datatables

I have one table and button. If I click on a button I need to generate table data in JSON format with one new key/value pair (the value is generated dynamically). The JSON I'm getting like this:

```
[{"id":"3","Test1":"Cartman","Test2":"123"},{"id":"3","Test1":"abc","Test2":"456"}]
```

I'm expecting JSON like this:

```
[{"sampledata":"123","id":"3","Test1":"Cartman","Test2":"123"},{"sampledata":"123","id":"3","Test1":"abc","Test2":"456"}]
```

I tried to add this dynamically but the data is not populated.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-kpi6ke?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Either loop through the array of objects to add the property (as in the marked duplicate), or alternatively instantiate the object with the default property: `jsonData1[index] = { sampledata: '123' };` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-eq1l4l?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Also note that you're working with an array of objects, not JSON. This is perhaps why your research didn't give you an appropriate answer